# Написать функцию из условия

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Сегодня на собеседовании был пример:

> sum(a)(b)(c)=a + b + c;

Нужно написать функцию `sum` так что бы строка `sum(a)(b)(c)=a + b + c;` выполнялась, и сделать это нужно с помощью замыкания.

Как это сделать, и что значит `sum(a)(b)(c)` (несколько кавычек подряд у функции)?

Comment: Думаю не совсем так. думаю что имелось ввиду, что выполнение конструкции sum(a)(b)(c) должно дать такой же результат как дает a+b+c ...

Comment: @Mike - точно :)

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Когда вам на собеседовании предлагают решить задачу, вы в свою очередь также предлагайте собеседующему решить задачу. Вам никто не делает отдолжение. Вы - на равных!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ну мне кажется мы не совсем на равных, все же собеседующий знает больше чем я и это я к ним пришёл, а не они ко мне

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов Вы совершенно не правы. Вы к ним не приходили. Вы с ними вместе встретились при обоюдном согласии. Вам деньги будут платить не за то, что вы пришли и им понравились. Вам деньги будут платить за работу, то есть за труд. Вы с ними на равных. А так как у большинства - психология РАБОВ, то фирмы и позволяют себе ХАМИТЬ и манипулировать другими как хотят.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Похоже, что хотели тоже, что и от героя этой статьи:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/226325/

Т.е. в идеале решение должно быть таким:

```
var sum = function (orig) {
      var inner = function (val) {
        return sum(parseInt(val + '', 10) === val ? orig + val : orig);
      };

      inner.valueOf = function () { return orig; };

      return inner;
    };
```

Плюсы этого решения очевидны: оно применимо к любому числу слагаемых, не только 3. Пример с тремя слагаемыми даётся, чтобы понять как человек подходит к решению проблемы: локально или глобально.

Comment: Что-то в примере не так: попробуйте alert(sum(1)(2)(3));

Comment: @user1651142 Это не серьезно. Вы не сможете понять, как человек подходит к решению глобально или локально. Он просто выдаст то решение, которое знает, или которое ему в данный момент пришло в голову. Это никак не связано с тем, мыслит ли он локально или глобально. Всегда сначала к решению любой задачи подходят локально. И лишь когда известно локальное решение, то стараются его обобщить и абстрагировать.

Comment: Чтобы алерт сработал, нужно еще переопределить `toString`:  `inner.toString = function () { return orig.toString(); };`

Comment: @Mik, В первичном вопросе не было просьбы сделать так:
    `alert(sum(1)(2)(3));`. Там было так: `sum(a)(b)(c)=a + b + c;` - здесь очевидно имеется в виду не присваивание, а проверка на "нестрогое" равенство: `==`. Т.е. `alert(sum(1)(2)(3) == 1 + 2 + 3)` должен дать `true` - проверьте.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, вы правы, хотя собеседуемым хочется видеть более комплексный подход к решению.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sum(a){
  return function(b){
    return function(c){
      return b+a+c;
    }
  }
}
alert(sum(1)(2)(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

`function sum(x) { return function(z) { return function(y) {return x+z+y;} } }`

Но что то мне подсказывает, что они хотели более элегантное решение, которое мне в голову пока не приходит.

Comment: Нет более элегантного, соответствующего заданным условиям.

Comment: @Mik Вот, дали в теме 4й ответ, вот он элегантный. главное - универсальный

Answer (score 1):

```
function sum(a) 
{ 
    return function(b) { 
        return function(c) { 
            return a + b + c; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Видимо имелось в виду вот это.

функция которая возвращает функцию, которая возвращает функцию, и ты вызываешь функцию у функции которая вернула функцию =)